# Wrong return address with Mozilla Thunderbird and Gmail

Tags: firefox, email, thunderbird, gmail

I have 4 Gmail accounts listed in Thunderbird. A while back I noticed when I send an email from one of the accounts, it goes to them and the email is fine, but the return address is one of my other ones.

Now some clients have my personal email address! I did a test and even if I make sure the from email is right - it still switched it.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Using Edit accounts menu, in identity section, you have 4 fields: nano, email, Reply To and Company. Check your "Reply to" field is empty (or filled with the email you want) for each account.